# MS Access: An error in vba of my form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a simple MS Access form that has 3 objects: a text box, a list box, and a button.  The intended use of the form is as follows: the user enters a name in the text box, selects an item from the list box, then clicks the button to add the data to a table.

However, when I click on the button, I keep getting the error message, "You can't reference property or a method for a control unless the control has the focus."

Below is my code.  Thanks!

```
Private Sub addRecord_button_Click()
    Dim CustomerName As String
    Dim CustomerType As String

    On Error GoTo Errhandler

    CustomerName = "[name not selected]"
    CustomerType = "[type not selected]"

    CustomerName = Customer_TextBox.Text

    Select Case Type_ListBox.ListIndex
        Case 0
            CustomerType = "Type 1"
        Case 1
            CustomerType = "Type 2"
        Case 2
            CustomerType = "Type 3"
    End Select

    'MsgBox ("Name: " & CustomerName & " and Type: " & CustomerType)

    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (CustomerName, CustomerType);"

Errhandler:
    MsgBox ("The following error has occured: " & Err & " - " & Error(Err))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.Text` property can only be used when the TextBox has focus. Try using the `.Value` property instead.

Try replacing the below line

```
CustomerName = Customer_TextBox.Text
```

with

```
CustomerName = Customer_TextBox.Value
```

Comment: Or, leave out a property entirely, i.e., `Me!Customer_Textbox` (also really should be specifying the parent form, i.e., Me!, since that distinguishes it from a reference to a variable).