# Unable to get Text value from Select Dropdown in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in access that contains a recordset that is to be populated based on the selection of a dropdown list. I have tested the query and it definitely works if I set the variable data directly. However, I cannot seem to get it to work. I attempted to set the value of a hidden text box in order to see if I could access the data that way, however, I continue to get the Run-time error: 2185 'You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has focus.

This is the code in the subroutine:

```
Private Sub pickdate_AfterUpdate()
  Me![pickdate].SetFocus
  Me![tb_HiddenDate] = Me![pickdate].Text
  Forms!mainForm!subForm.Requery
End Sub
```

As an aside, if I do `Debug.Print(Me![pickdate])` it simply returns the index of the selected item. Same thing for Me![pickdate].Value. Me![pickdate].Text throws the exception, even in the AfterUpdate handler for pickdate.

I have looked into this thread: [MS Access: An error in vba of my form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623686/ms-access-an-error-in-vba-of-my-form), but it does not work in this case. I am at my wit's end right now trying to figure out why this isn't working as expected. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Try Me![PickDate].column(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporarily change the After Update procedure to see what you're dealing with.  Perhaps `pickdate` includes 2 columns: the first a number; and the second the text you want to retrieve.

```vb
Private Sub pickdate_AfterUpdate()
Dim i As Long
Debug.Print "pickdate Value: " & Me![pickdate]
For i = 0 To (Me.pickdate.ColumnCount - 1)
    Debug.Print "Column " & i, Me.pickdate.Column(i)
Next
'Forms!mainForm!subForm.Requery
End Sub
```

View the output in the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>).

Comment: Well, when I run this code, I get `pickdate Value: 1` and `column 0 - 12/15/2008`. I can at least use the .Column(0) part for getting it to work as I need it to. I don't understand why .Text gives an error in this situation, even though it seems like it should be working correctly.

Comment: I don't see why either, since you had `pickdate.SetFocus` before asking for `pickdate.Text`.  But I almost never use the `.Text` property and I wouldn't worry about it here.